# Running a DHCP server without conflict

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, dhcp-server

I have a single chip computer running ubuntu on it and I want to run a dhcp server on it to give addresses to any machine connected directly to it. Since it is a portable computer, I regularly connect it to multiple networks.

The problem is, when I connect it to a network already running a DHCP server, it results in conflict and messes up my network. 
Is there any way to have the dhcp server running without it affecting the external network?
Any tips or alternative methods will be greatly appreciated!

PS: My chip doesn't support usbnet.

Comment: DHCP services should be fixed infrastructure (eg not portable) as they are only pertinent to a specific realm. This is just a bad conception. As for the technicals of your proposal, no, because DHCP operates using Layer2 broadcasts, there is no way to control which DHCP server is used, except by controlling the layer2 topology of the LAN. So, no. I have no idea what you would hope to accomplish by doing so anyway.

Comment: I want my computer to serve an IP address if it is directly connected to any device. I was looking at dhcp as one way of doing that. Are there any alternatives that you could suggest?

Comment: I agree that this is a bad idea altogether, but that doesn't answer the question. Why not try to pull an IP and if you can't, assume you're supposed to be the DHCP server

Comment: Thanks Brydon! That's looking like the only way to do it. It's not very clean but it should work. I'll try putting a script in if-up.d which should check if there is a conflict and then start a local dhcp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a network engineer, what I can tell you is that it's not your duty to protect the destination network. A healthy network should be able to prevent the unauthorized DHCP server from messing up the existing DHCP services. For example cisco has a feature called DHCP snooping.

> DHCP snooping is a security feature that acts like a firewall between
>   untrusted hosts and trusted DHCP servers. The DHCP snooping feature
>   performs the following activities:
>
> •Validates DHCP messages received from untrusted sources and filters
>   out invalid messages.
>
> •Rate-limits DHCP traffic from trusted and untrusted sources.
>
> •Builds and maintains the DHCP snooping binding database, which
>   contains information about untrusted hosts with leased IP addresses.
>
> •Utilizes the DHCP snooping binding database to validate subsequent
>   requests from untrusted hosts.

For detailed information, please check this [link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/snoodhcp.html)

Besides, if the destination network is using a hub which doesn't provide any security feature, your only solution might be disabling the DHCP service.

Answer (score 0):

I used to catch programmers who did that on my corporate world.
Having a rogue DHCP server can really mess things up. Think, the CEO is angry and missed an important meeting with some investors, because he got on the wrong DHCP segment. 
If you are lucky you can just get away with having your Port or MAC address disabled. Worst case the IT guy told the CEO exactly who was responsible for him missing his meeting, or you get slapped with a security violation.

You can get a USB ethernet stick, set the DHCP server to only give out addresses for that interface, plug in the interface when you need it. It's always good to go with the physical world.

Most of my developer would misconfigure virtual hosts, or plug in a router as a switch.
Hope this helps